# Insert value into specific row from another table

Tags: sql-server

I need help on the query to insert a value from one table to another. I have three tables, two contains email transaction volume data (Email_Transaction_Volume_13052020 and Email_Transaction_Volume_14052020) and another one in which i need to capture the volume for each subs to (daily_transaction_monitoring_working). Below is my query.

```
insert into daily_transaction_monitoring_working  (Carry_Forward )  
select sum(case_count_sum) 
from Email_Transaction_Volume_13052020 as b
where 
   b.status in ('Assigned', 'Awaiting Response', 'Internal Hold') and 
   b.Email_Source_Case = 'ssc.tseparts'

insert into daily_transaction_monitoring_working (Incoming)  
select sum(case_count_sum) 
from Email_Transaction_Volume_14052020 as b
where 
   b.status in ('Closed', 'No Response Required') and 
   b.Email_Source_Case = 'ssc.tseparts';
```

However, this resulted into inserting the value incoming and and carry forward into two rows (as shown below). Meanwhile I need it to be on the same row. Could anyone please help me with this.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may provide two subqueries as the source of data for the record you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO daily_transaction_monitoring_working (Carry_Forward, Incoming)
(
    SELECT SUM(case_count_sum)
    FROM Email_Transaction_Volume_13052020
    WHERE
        status IN ('Assigned', 'Awaiting Response', 'Internal Hold') AND
        Email_Source_Case = 'ssc.tseparts'
),
(
    SELECT SUM(case_count_sum)
    FROM Email_Transaction_Volume_14052020
    WHERE
        status IN ('Closed', 'No Response Required') AND
        Email_Source_Case = 'ssc.tseparts'
);
```

Comment: hi thank you, this would work if both inputs come from same table Email_Transaction_Volume_13052020 but one of the input actually is from Email_Transaction_Volume_14052020 table and one more is from Email_Transaction_Volume_13052020. Could you help if its from different tables

Comment: INSERT INTO daily_transaction_monitoring_working (Carry_Forward, Incoming)
select 
   ( SELECT SUM(case_count_sum)
    FROM Email_Transaction_Volume_13052020
    WHERE
        status IN ('Assigned', 'Awaiting Response', 'Internal Hold') AND
        Email_Source_Case = 'ssc.tseparts') as carry_forward , 


 (   SELECT SUM(case_count_sum)
    FROM Email_Transaction_Volume_14052020
    WHERE
        status IN ('Closed', 'No Response Required') AND
        Email_Source_Case = 'ssc.tseparts') as incoming 
;